# When I delete a character VoiceOver, deleted character is announced except second character

Tags: accessibility, voiceover

If I type the string "12345" in an input field, the correct character is announced as typed.

However, if I delete the characters one at a time, VoiceOver speaks "5 4 3 1 1".  It seems that when you delete the second to last character, the remaining character is announced instead.  Is this desired behavior that I don't understand?

I am seeing this issue consistently on my site, but have replicated on other sites, such as google.